# Syntax error possibly due to different ruby versions

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, syntax-error

I have this line of code in my function:

```
people << {"id": person.id, "name": person.name, "age": person.age}
```

This ran fine in my development environment. But in my friend's pc, it says there is a syntax error in this line. It says that the colon in `"id": person.id` is wrong. Writing the above code as `"id"=> person.id` fixed the issue. Is this issue possibly due to different ruby versions?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Your friend is probably using Ruby < v1.9.

That short syntax was introduced in 1.9. Before that it was all hash rocket (`=>`) syntax.

Comment: Yes, he's using 2.1.2 whereas I am using 2.2.0

Answer (score 2):

```
people << {"id": person.id, "name": person.name, "age": person.age}
```

This syntax is [new in 2.2.0](https://github.com/ruby/ruby/blob/v2_2_0/NEWS#L19-L20). Before 2.2, the `Symbol`s in the JSON-style `Hash` literals could only be valid Ruby identifiers (strictly speaking, valid Ruby *labels*) and could not be quoted.

See [Feature #4276: Allow use of quotes in symbol syntactic sugar for hashes](https://bugs.ruby-lang.org/issues/4276) for details.

> Writing the above code as `"id"=> person.id` fixed the issue.

Those two are *not* equivalent! The `Hash` above has `Symbol`s as keys, your replacement has `String`s as keys. There are several equivalent notations for the `Hash` literal above, but yours *isn't*:

```
{ id: person.id, name: person.name, age: person.age }                # 1.9+
{ 'id': person.id, 'name': person.name, 'age': person.age }          # 2.2+
{ :id => person.id, :name => person.name, :age => person.age }       # all versions
{ :'id' => person.id, :'name' => person.name, :'age' => person.age } # all versions
{ :"id" => person.id, :"name" => person.name, :"age" => person.age } # all versions
```

I ordered them roughly in order of preference, with the first one being the most preferred. You shouldn't quote `Symbol` literals that don't need quoting, and you shouldn't use double quotes if you don't intend to use interpolation.